# While scrolling the list ,the items in list are getting jumbled

Tags: android

While scrolling the list ,the items in list are getting jumbled.
I am using the base adapter for custom list.

My code is:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.list_challenge_comp_cell, null);
        holder.text_title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_title);
        holder.text_challenge = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_challenge);
        holder.text_enroll_date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_enroll_date);
        holder.text_rewards = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_rewards);
        holder.button_share = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_enroll);
        holder.progressBar = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        holder.layout_main = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout_main);
        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.button_share.setText("Share");

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
```

Comment: Please, define the jumbleness. Also, add a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  of your code.

Comment: post some code what you tried so far

Comment: Kindly post your `Adapter` code.

Answer (score 0):

Add the code in adapter,

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    // The total number of row types your adapter supports.
    // This should NEVER change at runtime.
    return VIEW_TYPE_COUNT;
}
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    // return a value from zero to (viewTypeCount - 1)
    if (position == 0) {
        return VIEW_TYPE_HEADER;
    } else if (position == getCount() - 1) {
        return VIEW_TYPE_FOOTER;
    }
    return VIEW_TYPE_DEFAULT;
}
```

and use

> View holder

[Reference link](https://dzone.com/articles/optimizing-your-listview)